# component does not change state for each element in the array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, react-props

The scenario is when I click a button, it loads a set of cards based on the elements of an array, 
When I click another button it too loads the set of cards native to that button

Below is the code which will get each card for an array element

```js
{!!props[props.clickedindex].Products
   ? (props[props.clickedindex].Products.map((Products, i)=> <CardProduct {...props[props.clickedindex].Products} key={i} index={i} arrkey={Object.keys(Products)} /> ))
                  : (<div />)}
```

**Here is the code for the card**

The problem is when I click the first button and there are only 3 elements I get the three colors perfectly based on the props the state changes

But when click the second button  and there are 6 elements, the first 3 retains the same state and color and doesn't update at all

I believe I am mutating if so help me how Not To

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardContent, CardMedia, CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card';
import { Typography, Grid, Button, Paper } from 'material-ui';

//{styles removed for easy reading}

class CardProduct extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            background: '#ffffff'
        }
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        const { props } = this

        console.log(props.arrkey[0].toString())
        switch (props.arrkey[0].toString()) {
            case 'Passion':
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#EF5350' })
                )
                break
            case "Love":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#FFB74D' })
                )
                break
            case "Intelligence":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#42A5F5' })
                )
                break
            case "Anger":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#78909C' })
                )
                break
            case "Perseverance":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#8D6E63' })
                )
                break
            case "determination":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#66BB6A' })
                )
                break
            case "Speed":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#EC407A' })
                )
                break
            case "Focus":
                return (
                    this.setState({ background: '#8D6E63' })
                )
                break
            default: return this.state;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { props } = this
        const { classes } = this.props;


        console.log('THIS IS PROPS IN PRODUCTCARD,', props.arrkey[0], this.state, props[props.index],props)

        return (
            <div >

                <Card className={classes.card} >
                    <div
                        className={classes.media}
                        style={{ background: this.state.background }}>
                        <Typography style={{ color: '#000000' }} gutterBottom variant="caption" component="h2" align='center' >
                            {`${props.arrkey}`}
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                    <CardContent style={{ padding: '1vw', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="caption" component="h2" align='center' >
                            {`${props[props.index][props.arrkey]}`}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>

                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

CardProduct.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CardProduct);
```

Comment: Try using a key which is not i or index. Maybe it's not re-rendering the element

Comment: Yes it is , I did a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Did this workaround Hope this is the right method

```js
 colorChooser = (props) => {

        switch (props.arrkey[0].toString()) {
            case 'Relationship':
                return (
                    this.CardDiv('#EF5350' )
                )
                break
            case "Marriage":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv( '#FFB74D' )
                )
                break
            case "Children":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv('#42A5F5' )
                )
                break
            case "yearly":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv( '#78909C' )
                )
                break
            case "Monthly":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv('#8D6E63' )
                )
                break
            case "Questions":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv('#66BB6A' )
                )
                break
            case "Matching":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv('#EC407A' )
                )
                break
            case "Career":
                return (
                    this.CardDiv( '#66BB6A' )
                )
                break
            default: return this.CardDiv('#ffffff');

        }
    }

    CardDiv = (bgcolor) => {
        const { props } = this
        const classes = props.classes
        return (
            <div
                className={classes.media}
                style={{ background:(bgcolor.toString()) }}>
                <Typography style={{ color: '#000000' }} gutterBottom variant="caption" component="h2" align='center' >
                    {`${props.arrkey}`}
                </Typography>
            </div>)
    }

    render() {
        const { props } = this
        const { classes } = this.props;


        console.log('THIS IS PROPS IN PRODUCTCARD,', props.arrkey[0], this.state, props[props.index])

        return (
            <div >

                <Card className={classes.card} >
                {this.colorChooser(props)}

                    <CardContent style={{ padding: '1vw', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="caption" component="h2" align='center' >
                            {`${props[props.index][props.arrkey]}`}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>

                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
```